# I get an error when cloning from BitBucket to SourceTree

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

### When the error occurred:

When trying to clone a repository from BitBucket to SourceTree when building a virtual environment

### Error Message

```sh
git -c filter.lfs.smudge= -c filter.lfs.required=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks clone --branch master ***************** C:\**********
Cloning into 'C:\***************'...
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

### What I tried

- Restart your PC,
- re-login to BitBucket
- restart SoureTree

I get the same error when I try it in another repository.

Sorry to trouble you, but I would appreciate it if anyone who knows how to deal with it would let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [in this thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/The-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly/qaq-p/808993):

> This error indicates that something has interrupted your traffic.
> It doesn't really say what caused the interruption - whether it was Bitbucket, or something on your local network, or something else.
> From experience, in many cases this has been caused by network bandwidth. You can try using a different network and if that still doesn't work, you could do
>
> ```
> git config --global core.compression 1
> ```
>
> where 1 means "fastest compression".